# SQL variable hold only last result returned

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

Below statement stores and prints the last result returned. How can I store both the values?

Table name: `UserGroupBranchMapping`

```
UserId      username           IsActive CountryName    AccessType
----------- ------------------ -------- -------------  ------------
140         demo1@demo1.com    1        SOUTH AFRICA   2
140         demo1@demo1.com    1        BOTSWANA       1
```

SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @AccessType VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @username NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @countryName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @countryId VARCHAR(100);

SET @username = 'demo1@demo1.com,demo2@demo1.com';
SET @countryName = 'SOUTH AFRICA,BOTSWANA';

SELECT @AccessType = ugbm.AccessType, @countryId = ugbm.Countryid
FROM UserGroupBranchMapping ugbm
INNER JOIN Users usr ON usr.id = ugbm.UserId
INNER JOIN Country con ON con.id = ugbm.countryid
WHERE usr.UserName IN (SELECT item
                       FROM dbo.SplitString(@username, ','))
  AND con.countryName IN (SELECT item
                          FROM dbo.SplitString(@countryName, ','))
  AND ugbm.IsActive = 1;

PRINT @AccessType, @countryId
```

Comment: Use a temporary table or a table variable. a **scalar** variable can only hold a **scalar** (1) value.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to PRINT the values instead of simply `SELECT`ing them without using any variables?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis;
yes the reason to do
 IF AccessType = 1 then I am executing select statement to the group branch branch details
and if AccessType equals 2 then  I am executing another select statement to get the company details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already Larnu said, a **scalar variable hold 1 (one) value at a time**. When the query execution reaches the end of a batch command (most probably you use the default one which is `GO`), the variable is auto-destroyed, meaning that loses the value held until that point.

If you want to hold more values into multiple columns at the same time, you should use a table variable.

You may use something like this:

```
DECLARE @UserGroupBranchMapping TABLE(
UserId int,
username nvarchar(200),
isActive bit,
CountryName nvarchar(200),
AccessType int
)


INSERT INTO @UserGroupBranchMapping (UserId, username, isActive, CountryName, AccessType)
VALUES(140, N'demo1@demo1.com', 1, N'SOUTH AFRICA', 2), (140, N'demo1@demo1.com', 1, N'BOTSWANA', 1)
```

The following `SELECT` statement will produce the below result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @UserGroupBranchMapping

UserId  username        isActive    CountryName   AccessType
------------------------------------------------------------
140     demo1@demo1.com    1        SOUTH AFRICA      2
140     demo1@demo1.com    1        BOTSWANA          1
```

Be careful that the table variable have a similar behavior as a scalar variable, meaning that when it reach the batch command, it lose all values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But how can I executed the scenario.
If the Access Type is 1, then execute select statement to get group branch details else execute the company details select statement.

Comment: @Dipak - this is another topic. Please ask a new question for this. If my suggestion helped, please accept it. Thanks!